# Nginx returning 404 on seemingly valid path

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, openbsd

I'm trying to serve static files directly with a location block like this:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /opt/graphite/webapp/content/;
}
```

But when I make a request for anything matching /static/, I get a 404 error, and a message like this in the error log:

```
2016/09/14 09:28:47 [error] 66068#0: *4 open() "/opt/graphite/webapp/content/js/completer.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: my.ip.add.ress, server: server.domain, request: "GET /static/js/completer.js HTTP/1.1", host: "server.ip", referrer: "http://server.ip/composer?"
```

The thing is that the path given in that error message is completely valid. That file exists. It's not claiming permission denied, so it doesn't seem like a permissions issue. The location that proxies to the app works fine. I'm at a loss, and similar posts all seem to pertain to sockets.

Running nginx 1.10.1 on OpenBSD 6.0.

Comment: Permissions is most likely Please post permissions for the object, including owner and group, and tell us what user / groups Nginx is running as.

Comment: Permissions of the object are 644, owned by www:www, which is the user that nginx is running as. Directory is 775, also www:www.

Comment: I would try adding a second line to your location block with a `try_files` directive and point it to a distinct error (like '499') on fail instead of 404 to confirm this is tripping. Second, try rewriting your location block with a regex and using `root` instead of `alias`.

Comment: Tried that. Successfully returns a `499` after the `try_files` fails (though no error is logged, since `try_files` coming back empty doesn't count as an error). I was using `alias` because the URL structure doesn't correspond directly to the directory structure, but after remediating that, I get the same behavior. Logged error claiming that a file which exists does not exist.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of all of the parent directories?

Comment: Global read and execute all the way up to the root.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, I can read the files that aren't returned with `sudo -i www cat /opt/graphite/webapp/content/js/*`, which would seem to indicate that permissions are not the problem.

Comment: Could it be something really simple like a path mismatch? Are you 100% sure your base URL is set correctly? What is the full path of this file on the file system?

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. The distribution of nginx in OpenBSD defaults to chrooting into `/var/www/`, which denies access to the entire filesystem outside of that section. This can be circumvented by starting nginx directly with the `-u` flag, or adding that same flag to the command in `/etc/rc.d/nginx`.

Alternatively, moving everything into the chroot is pretty trivial, once you know that's what's happening.

Comment: Always good to check the OpenBSD manpage for nginx. Not a well advertised feature, and if you administer different boxes you may be caught out whether the binaries on the machine are built from ports (includes -u un-chroot) or src (not include -u)